# Convert date and time format from PHP to JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem that in my MySQL, the date and time data is saved as `Y-mm-dd H:m:s`. How can I switch to the date and time to JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

Your date is saved as date in sql.

When you have a backend, an ajax request from browser can get a date or bigger structure as json (serialized as string). Sample:
`{ date: "2020-05-23T16:29:48.973Z" }.`.

This date can be (should be) in an iso format, see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) .
This date string can be parsed by javascript easily:

```
let dateObj = new Date("2020-05-23T16:29:48.973Z");
```

This object can be formatted (object -> string) with help of [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat).

```
let str = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(dateObj);
console.info('date: ', str);
```